# Hive insert and load data query is not working

Tags: hadoop, hive

My hive query is not working. Hive allowing me to create the databases, show databases and create table as well but it don't allow me to move local file to into HDFS table and insert query is also not working. 
I tried reinitialize my metastore and format namenode and created again every directory. But still anything is not working.
My datanode is not starting. Is this problem related to datanode? What should I do.

Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask. Error caching map.xml.
This error is coming when I try to run any query except create table and databases.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the errors above ,You will not be able to write in hdfs.

> Hive allowing me to create the databases, show databases and create
>   table as well but it don't allow me to move local file to into HDFS
>   table and insert query is also not working.

```
Freeing up the HDFS Space would work
```

Comment: its not related to the data node?

Comment: cleaned up the space?..it says there are 0 datanodes..how can we say that its not related ..